# Filtering view of subsites by permission

Tags: 2007, site, security-trimming

I have a site with *many* subsites. Only a portion of these subsites need to be (or should be) accessible by a particular user. Is there a way I can have some sort of list view on my parent site page that displays only relevant subsites to any particular user?

Right now all of the sites appear in the quick launch. This isn't what I want. I would prefer it to be displayed as a link list of some sort in the center of the page. It will essentially be the main content of the parent site.

I'm using WSS 3.0 and I do not currently have the ability to develop a custom solution.

Comment: Tested this in 2010 with a tree view and it works as you'd like. Have you tried tree view in 2007?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by *relevant* sites, you are referring to sites the user has access to. If this is the case, you can create a data view web part based on search results that displays only sites (and not documents/lists/etc.). [@WonderLaura](http://twitter.com/wonderlaura) has an example/walk-through of how to create such a web part on her [blog](http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=676af157-7d96-4e15-a987-54b8a3e4d948&ID=98).

This often works best if you use a scoped query along with the fixed keywords.